# How to stop the enemy rotate when the player collide with it

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have been try for a while to stop the enemy rotate wen my player collide with it. I have insert a rigid body, and I have try to freeze position and also the freeze rotation but he keep doing the same, I can't find any were any info to learn about this problem.

I have google it a few times and could not find any thing, close to my problem.
This is the screenshot of the problem

https://i.stack.imgur.com/F97Z7.jpg

Also I have tried to set Angular drag to 0 but no success it keep doing the same.
It sounds like I am missing something, but I can't find any solution for it yet.

I have also tried to see all answers on unity forum but I can't find anywhere a solution or the way to learn about this problem.

I have edit to insert the enemy script
This is my enemy script

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;


public class target : MonoBehaviour {

public float health = 100f;

public Animator animx2;
public AudioSource audiovfx2;


public void TakeDamage (float amount)
{
    health -= amount;
    if (health <= 0f) 
    {
        Die();
    }
}

void Die()
{
    animx2.SetBool("isdie",true);
    audiovfx2.Play();
    healthcontroller.score += 10;
    health -= 10;
    Destroy (gameObject, 1.5f);

}
void Update()
{

    animx2 = GetComponent<Animator>();
    GetComponent<AudioSource>().Play();
}
void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other) {
    if (other.tag == "Player") {
        Rigidbody rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
        rb.angularVelocity = Vector3.zero
        //Stop Moving/Translating
        //rbdy.velocity = Vector3.zero;

        //Stop rotating
        //rbdy.angularVelocity = Vector3.zero;
    }


}

void OnTriggerExit(Collider other) {
    if (other.tag == "Player") {
        //here i want to return to normal
    }
}
}
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try to nullify `angularVelocity` of the Rigidbody component, for example

> rb.angularVelocity = Vector3.zero;

Comment: tank you for answer , i have try just now to add it and also i need declare a variable,  what is the variable of rd pls.

Comment: I just solve it tank you , i need to use the animator variable

Comment: error CS0200: Property or indexer `UnityEngine.Animator.angularVelocity' cannot be assigned to (it is read only)

Comment: It's preferable to stop the Rigidbody from rotating that way, even the animator will stop.

Comment: tank you again for the great help , i have try to define rd as a rigidbody variable but its sounds like i missing somethings i can not make it work, can you pls give a small example of it, tank you in advance

Comment: I need to know before that, where are you detecting collisions? inside the Player script, or Enemy script?

Comment: insert this code in the end of onTriggerEnter

`Rigidbody rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
rb.angularVelocity = Vector3.zero`

Comment: I noticed you are only stopping the PLAYER from rotating, but as for the ENEMY you didn't

Comment: Tank you for the replay well in this case i want to prevent only the enemy to rotate because the player dont do any way if i take this script

Comment: How can i do the same but for the enemy because i have try to insert on were you say and its continue to do the same

Comment: then, it must be something else that triggers the rotation mechanism, can you repost the new code?

Comment: I just repost the new code sorry but i have only 15 points so i am not able to do in chat

Comment: Okay, you are really confused, look, you have a variable called 'rd' and 'rb', they are both Rigidbody, it means they are the same.. here is what to do:

1> delete 'rd', you won't need it cuz you already have 'rb'
2> that line `Rigidbody rb = ...` move it inside at the end of the brackets of that `if`
3> add the line that nullify angularVelocity
like so `rb.angularVelocity = Vector3.zero`

Comment: i just repost my code after made the alterations can u pls verify if its like that pls